# How can i connect my python script with Android application?

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, android-studio, web-scraping

Well,I wanna scrap data with my python script and want to show it into android application.

As we use PHP API's for database or other stuff and send and receive data in android in JSON.How can i do the same things with python scripts?

Thanks in advance,Have a good day.